# Android - Set listener marker

Tags: android, google-maps

in my googleMap there are 5 markers.
Is there a method by which I can set a listener just on one of them?
The code below shows how to do this, but only if there is a single marker:

```
GoogleMap mMap
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
   new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(dLat, dLong))
   .title("Your title")                                       
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin)));

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {
}
}
```

Comment: You can idenfiy markers by Tag assigned and then after identification, you can perform your operation check my answer below , hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: did you try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you are adding marker , you can add Tag to each Marker,

like this

```
 marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(yourPosition)
                    .title("yourTitle");
  marker1.setTag("YourTag");
```

> and then you can identify which Marker is clicked by accessing the
>   Tag value in `OnMarkerClickListener`.

```
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {

                       if(m.getTag()=="YourTag"){
                        //Perfom your operation here
                       }else if(m.getTag()=="AnotherTag"){
                        //Perfom your operation here
                       }
    }
```

Comment: thanks thunder, but, like in this case, writing ' if(m.getTag()=="0") ' nothing happens.

Comment: Before doing this first you need to set tag to the marker , after you create marker

Comment: Thunder, as I sayd, if I write:  marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(yourPosition)
                    .title("yourTitle");
  marker1.setTag(0);      and then:    if(m.getTag()=="0"), nothing happens, it doesn't enter into the if tree

Comment: You are settling as integer and then trying to compare with String that's why it's not working

Comment: 0 and "0" is different mate

Comment: Or in your case just do like this marker.setTag("0");